# How to store a 2D array of strings containing common delimited characters in Python?

Tags: python, arrays, json, multidimensional-array

I am trying to store a large number of news articles (eventually maybe more than several thousand) that I am using in a Python script. For convenience, I would like to store them in a 2D array within a text file, like [[ID, Title, Article],[1, 'Bill's Burgers', 'The owner, Bill, makes good burgers."]]. However, the solutions I find online require some character such as comma, space, newline, etc to delimited the entries. As these commonly appear in news articles, I can't use them to delimited elements.

I tried to format my 2D array using json, but found this didn't do anything to my array. When printing/opening the txt file, it appears exactly as when I declare it - "[[[["ID", "URL", "Title", "Date", "Article"],["1","2","3","4","5"]]". My code is as follows:

```
scraped_articles_array_headings = [["ID", "URL", "Title", "Date", "Article"],["1","2","3","4","5"]]
headings_encoded = json.dumps(scraped_articles_array_headings)
print(headings_encoded)
f = open("articles_encoded2.txt", "w", encoding="utf-8")
f.write(headings_encoded)
f.close()
```

How am I mis-using json here? I would welcome any suggestions regarding a suitable approach to storing this data - Ideally I just want a system to allow for easy searching of the contents of each parameter (ID, Title, etc) and I appreciate the above approach might not be following a sensible path to achieve this.

Comment: Sounds like a case for a relational database

Comment: What's exactly the issue with your current code?

Comment: I have added some extra depth - in short json isn't encoding the array - when I view the txt file or print the array, it appears exactly as when I declare it.

Comment: what does that mean? I think you’ll need to `json.load` it when you’re reading the file back, right?

Comment: What does "in short json isn't encoding the array " mean, **exactly**? The JSON module will handle your text just fine. What exactly is the problem? it isn't clear

Comment: Ah i see, it looks like you’re trying to store data on each line, similar to a CSV format file? In that case, I am not too sure that json would be the best use case here actually. It looks like you are mixing csv and json concepts together here — not sure that it would be advised.

Comment: " Ideally I just want a system to allow for easy searching of the contents of each parameter (ID, Title, etc) and I appreciate the above approach might not be following a sensible path to achieve this." Is this related to your attempt to store this information? It's hard to understand what you are trying to achieve and how your current approach isn't suitable.

Comment: "As these commonly appear in news articles, I can't use them to delimited(sic) elements."  Sure you can.  A CSV can quote delimiters and escape quotes in its columns.  The `csv` module or `pandas.write_csv()` will handle the escaping/quoting.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may want to look into an example JSON formatted document.
Keep in mind that this is different from a CSV format which is line based and uses a delimiter as you've mentioned.

To store those values in JSON you may want to do something like this:

```json
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "url": "https://example.com",
        "title": "Example Title",
        "date": "21-03-2003",
        "article": "Some article content..."
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "url": "https://example.com",
        "title": "Example Title",
        "date": "21-03-2003",
        "article": "Some article content..."
    }
]
```

For storing large amounts of data you may want to consider a database to improve performance and also allows for querying (eg. finding all articles from a certain URL).

Answer (score 0):

You can have articles that contain "comma, space, newline, etc" and still use common formats that use them for delimiters.  An example using the Python `csv` module:

```py
import csv

scraped_articles = [['ID', 'URL', 'Title', 'Date', 'Article'],
                    ['1','2','3','4','article1 with\n "quotes" and commas(,) and newlines'],
                    ['1','2','3','4','article2 with\n "quotes" and commas(,) and newlines']]

with open('articles.csv', 'w', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerows(scraped_articles)

with open('articles.csv', 'r', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f)
    for line in reader:
        print('-'*80)
        print(line['Article'])
    print('-'*80)
```

Resulting `articles.csv`:

```
ID,URL,Title,Date,Article
1,2,3,4,"article1 with
 ""quotes"" and commas(,) and newlines"
1,2,3,4,"article2 with
 ""quotes"" and commas(,) and newlines"
```

Output after reading data back:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
article1 with
 "quotes" and commas(,) and newlines
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
article2 with
 "quotes" and commas(,) and newlines
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```